# how to get the answer from QnA maker in azure bot framework using nodejs and then update the answer manually?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

how to get the answer from QnA maker in azure bot framework using nodejs and then update the answer manually programmatically before showing in emulator
I want to change the actual answer returned by the QnA maker service and then show it. In rootDialog.js file there is a method called async startInitialDialog(step) where within the method there is a call to step.beginDialog(QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG); But when I catch the return data and change the answer property, it is not reflecting.
The sample return json is as follows:

```
{
  status: 'complete',
  result: [
    {
      questions: [Array],
      answer: 'Hello.',
      score: 1,
      id: 198,
      source: 'qna_chitchat_professional.tsv',
      metadata: [Array],
      context: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to change the property answer of Hello to something else. But when I run in emulator, it still says Hello

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying? What do you mean by 'update'? Are you changing the actual answer, or are you changing the formatting?

Comment: Yes I want to change the actual answer returned by the QnA maker service and then show it.  
In rootDialog.js file there is a method called async startInitialDialog(step) where within the method there is a call to step.beginDialog(QNAMAKER_BASE_DIALOG);
But when I catch the return data and change the answer property, it is not reflecting.

Comment: I have updated with few details and the sample json. Please help

Comment: If your QnA is returning 'Hello', why do you want to change it? If it's not the correct 'answer' to your QnA 'question', you can train it on the QnA portal.

Comment: It is just an example of Hello. But I need to change it in some scenarios where I need to add values dynamically. Let's say an example where I want to append values that are being fetched from DB or some server.

Comment: Hi @ArnabMandal, did you figure this out yet? I am struggling with something similar

Comment: Hi Did you find how to resolve this?